# Запись в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql

При попытке добавления в таблицу записи из формы выдает следующее сообщение:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES('', '', '21:54:00', '2018-09-03', '' )' at line 1

Вот код:

```
$virable = "INSERT INTO fk (title, text, time, date, author,) 
                        VALUES('$title', '$text', '$time', '$date', '$author' )";
            $result = mysqli_query ($connect, $virable) or die ("Ошибка: ".mysqli_error($connect));//запись в таблицу
            if ($result)
            {
                echo "Запись произведена";
            }
```

Переменные:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
```

Comment: Запятая после `author` лишняя.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, первое - у Вас лишняя запятая здесь:

> (title, text, time, date, author,)

Должно быть `(title, text, time, date, author)`

А второе - Вы никак не валидируете входящие параметры - title & text - пустые.

Настоятельно рекомендую посмотреть в сторону [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) и [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score -2):

Пример записи в БД:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Если вы исключаете то, что в $_POST ваши переменные - пустые, то попробуйте убрать лишние "кавычки"

```
VALUES('$title', '$text', '$time', '$date', '$author' )";
```

Кавычки нужны в случае, если вы передаете в качестве значения не переменную типа **string**, а вручную пишите строковое значение, к примеру **'John'**.